# Getting error while trying to create a View in Xamarin Studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, xamarin

I am getting this error when trying to create a new View in an ASP.Net MVC 4 project in Xamarin Studio. There are no pending updates in my setup. How can I fix this?

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. ---> System.TypeLoadException: A type
>   load exception has occurred.   at
>   MonoDevelop.AspNet.Mvc.Gui.FolderCommandHandler.AddView () [0x00070]
>   in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-license-sync/c5f82958/source/monodevelop/main/src/addins/AspNet/MonoDevelop.AspNet.Mvc/Gui/FolderNodeBuilderExtension.cs:154
>   at (wrapper managed-to-native)
>   System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke
>   (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)   at
>   System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[]
>   parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00054] in
>   /private/tmp/source/bockbuild-xamarin/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-3.2.5/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:230
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---   at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[]
>   parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00069] in
>   /private/tmp/source/bockbuild-xamarin/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-3.2.5/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:238
>   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj,
>   System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in
>   /private/tmp/source/bockbuild-xamarin/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-3.2.5/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MethodBase.cs:114
>   at MonoDevelop.Components.Commands.DefaultCommandHandler.Run
>   (System.Object target, MonoDevelop.Components.Commands.Command cmd)
>   [0x00019] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-license-sync/c5f82958/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Components.Commands/CommandManager.cs:2094
>   at MonoDevelop.Components.Commands.CustomCommandTargetAttribute.Run
>   (System.Object target, MonoDevelop.Components.Commands.Command cmd)
>   [0x00009] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-license-sync/c5f82958/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Components.Commands/CustomCommandTargetAttribute.cs:101
>   at
>   MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Components.NodeCommandHandler+TransactedNodeHandlerAttribute.Run
>   (System.Object target, MonoDevelop.Components.Commands.Command cmd)
>   [0x0002d] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-license-sync/c5f82958/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Components/NodeCommandHandler.cs:296
>   at
>   MonoDevelop.Components.Commands.CustomCommandTargetAttribute.MonoDevelop.Components.Commands.ICommandTargetHandler.Run
>   (System.Object target, MonoDevelop.Components.Commands.Command cmd)
>   [0x00004] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-license-sync/c5f82958/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Components.Commands/CustomCommandTargetAttribute.cs:58
>   at MonoDevelop.Components.Commands.CommandHandlerInfo.Run
>   (System.Object cmdTarget, MonoDevelop.Components.Commands.Command cmd)
>   [0x00021] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-license-sync/c5f82958/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Components.Commands/CommandManager.cs:1963
>   at
>   MonoDevelop.Components.Commands.CommandManager+c_*AnonStorey82.<>m*_D2
>   () [0x0005f] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-license-sync/c5f82958/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Components.Commands/CommandManager.cs:1054
>   at MonoDevelop.Components.Commands.CommandManager.DispatchCommand
>   (System.Object commandId, System.Object dataItem, System.Object
>   initialTarget, CommandSource source) [0x002b0] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-license-sync/c5f82958/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Components.Commands/CommandManager.cs:1071

Comment: I had this issue, but just updating the IDE resolved it.